# Please explain this code snippet

Tags: javascript, html

I came across this code while I was browsing for html5 canvas examples.
I have pasted the code and I have given a comment in the place where i have a doubt.

```
if(window.addEventListener) {

  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var canvas, context, tool;

  function init () {
    canvas = document.getElementById('imageView');
    if (!canvas) {
      alert('Error: I cannot find the canvas element!');
      return;
    }

    if (!canvas.getContext) {
      alert('Error: no canvas.getContext!');
      return;
    }

     context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (!context) {
      alert('Error: failed to getContext!');
      return;
    }

        tool = new tool_pencil();

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',   ev_canvas, false);
  }

   function tool_pencil () {
    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;


    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(ev._x, ev._y);
        tool.started = true;
    };

      this.mousemove = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
        context.stroke();
      }
    };

       this.mouseup = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        tool.mousemove(ev);
        tool.started = false;
      }
    };
  }

    function ev_canvas (ev) {
    if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { 
      ev._x = ev.layerX;
      ev._y = ev.layerY;
    } else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) { 
      ev._x = ev.offsetX;
      ev._y = ev.offsetY;
    }

    //Please explain the follwing set of line
    var func = tool[ev.type];
    if (func) {
      func(ev);
    }
  }

  init();

}, false); }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In conjunction with other answers, what it's doing is putting all the callbacks in the one object. The result is that `func` is `tool.onmousedown`, `tool.onmouseup`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Please explain the follwing set of line
var func = tool[ev.type]; // Set func to the tool object's member 
                          // named 'event.type' 
                          // Will set func to undefined if no function is 
                          // found in the tool object
if (func) {  // if a func was found then call it.
  func(ev);
}
```

Note that the `tool` hash object is being used to hold function references, not scalars such as 1, "a string", etc. A feature of Javascript is that you can create, save, pass functions at runtime.

**Added** Thank you @Chris Morgan for pointing out that an_obj['unknown_key'] == undefined, not null.

Also note that foo['a_key'] is the runtime way of saying foo.a_key -- the 'a_key' member of the object 'foo'.

And finally, Javascript does not have hashes. It has objects which work reasonably well as the Hash type found in other languages.

**Added some more** (after looking at all of the code, not just the part in question). The code is creating an object `tool`. It has a number of members:

- `started` flag
- `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `mousemove` functions

The snippet of code is trying to locate the function that matches the event's type. So in this case, the object `tool` is being used as an object, not as a hash. I've updated the first part of the answer appropriately.

Comment: func will be `undefined`, not `null`, if it's not defined.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's trying to assign a "tool" of type `ev.type` to the variable `func`. This should be a function. It then checks if the function exists (ie. if it was assigned or not) and calls it if it does, passing the `ev` variable as a parameter.